# Executing JavaScript on a single page

Tags: javascript, popup, overlay, execute

I have created a js pop up overlay.. I'm trying to get it to display/execute on the homepage of the site **only** below is the code I have so far:

```
var overlay = "<div id='overlay'><div id='my_popup'><button id='popupbutton'>Click</button></div>    </div>";
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', overlay);

var button = document.getElementById('popupbutton');

button.onclick = function() {
var div = document.getElementById('overlay');
if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
    div.style.display = 'none';
}
else {
    div.style.display = 'block';
}
};
```

I've looked into:

```
if (window.location.href.split('/').pop() == "myURL")
```

but I can't get my head around getting it to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your homepage have `/` path or something else?

Comment: When I run that href split code on this page I get "executing-javascript-on-a-single-page", the last element in the array on splitting.  What are you trying to get?

Comment: No the homepage URL would be http://brooksbarn.com - I want the js code to only execute on this page, and not any subURL's of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to distinguish homepage using `location.pathname` property:

```
if (location.pathname === '/') {
    // homepage
}
```

In your example if you are on page `brooksbarn.com` then `location.pathname` will be `/`.